# Low Quality Posts review chokes when I run out of delete votes

Tags: bug, review

Most days I run out of delete votes somewhere in the middle of the Low Quality Posts queue.

I have noticed what seems to me to be a (minor) bug here.

When I get to my last delete vote, if I click the **Delete** button and then **Delete** again in the comment dialog, I get a little red error pop up saying:

> An error occurred while reviewing this item

I refresh the page, and I get this:

[image]

So, it looks like I cannot review this item at all.

**Edit:** However, [as pointed out in the comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16785/low-quality-posts-review-chokes-when-i-run-out-of-delete-votes#comment34066_16785), it appears that [the delete vote landed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879352/ubuntu14-04-login-loop-installed-teamviewer/888429#888429). A bit annoying, but not as bad as I first thought.

Comment: You can refresh the browser and you will be able to review it.

Comment: The above is what I get after refresh - will it be fixed by refreshing again? I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it actually works. Your "Recommend deletion" vote should be recorded.

Comment: I see that your delete vote worked.

Comment: So it did! I've edited the question.